# What is a good approach for Scalable k-means?

Tags: clustering, k-means, large-data

how can we use a distributed system (cluster of machines) to get final k-means centroids that are exactly equal to the centroids we would get if we were to process the same huge dataset on a single machine?

Comment: Treat each of the $k$ centroid seeds separate, ensuring: *1)* they are spread well throughout the entire space, *2)* do not converge to the same centroid (i.e. repel). Something like this?

Comment: Please do not cross-post duplicate questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49822049/what-is-a-good-approach-for-scalable-k-means

Answer (score 0):

You could try splitting the data series into intervals, running the algorithm on each interval, then combining intervals to rerun the algorithm, then eventually arrive at one final round. The intervals should be big enough to worth bothering, but small enough to make sure that each interval is decently far enough from the next.

This is a good read using the same intuition: https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4176